# Vim character search replace function error

Tags: vim

I have several documents that I want to selectively search-and-replace some non-ASCII characters (ie. replace `À` with `&Agrave;`). I have created a function in my _vimrc so that I can call it for any document but it gives me a "Pattern not found" error. But a simple search-and-replace in the target document works fine - it finds and replaces the characters as expected.

How can I get this function working like the normal search-and-replace?

(I'm using gvim on windows and all the documents are unix filetypes with utf-8 encoded.)

Here's the function in _vimrc

```
function! Hc()
    execute '%s/À/\&Agrave;/g'
endfunction
```

Which gives me the follow error when I `:call Hc()` in the target document:

```
Error detected while processing function Hc:
line   1:
E486: Pattern not found: Ã€
```

But it seems I can successfully execute this in the target document:

```
:%s/À/\&Agrave;/g
```

Any suggestions, corrections, or work-arounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an encoding error in your `~/.vimrc`. If you use non-ASCII characters, be sure to specify the file's encoding with

```
:scriptencoding utf-8
```

at the top of the file, and only define customizations after this line:

```
:set encoding=utf-8
```

#### Alternative workaround

You can also work around encoding issues by using one of the `\%d`, `\%x`, or `\%u` atoms, e.g.

```
:execute '%s/\%d192/\&Agrave;/g'    " À is decimal 192 in UTF-8.
```

Comment: The _vimrc is already utf-8 and I have the line `set fileencodings=utf-8`. But the Alternative workaround seems to be working so I think I'll have to use this. Thanks!

Comment: The problem stems from the encoding changed between [function] definition and use. The alternative is indeed safer, so if that works for you, fine!

Comment: That's what I was thinking as well but when I execute `:set fileencoding` in either the target file or _vimrc I get `fileencoding=utf-8`. So it seems to me that there should not be a problem with encoding change between the files.